# Javascript fade function on tag

Tags: javascript

I can get this to work in the first form, how do I achieve the same effect with the second get element by tag name doesn't work, (the node number '[0]' is correct) - any advice appreciated.

Note: media is the id attached to the video tag but I would prefer to attach it to the tag itself.

First:

```
function fade(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("media");
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Second:

```
function fade(){
    var elem = document.getElementByTagName("video")[0];
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share a sample of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **s** from getElement**s**ByTagName:

```
function fade(){
        var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
        elem.style.transition = "opacity 5s linear 0s";
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName